# Felix/Karaf dev:watch

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, apache-karaf

I am using "dev:watch *" in a karaf container to simplify my testing.

At the moment I deploy all my bundles as "xyz.SNAPSHOT" - and they are picked up correctly.

Question: If I make released bundles (without this ".SNAPSHOT" - will this dev:watch work too?

Answer (score 2):

It won't work with this command:

```
karaf@root> dev:watch *
```

From the help of this command:

> It will actually monitor all bundles that have a location matching
>   mvn:* that have '-SNAPSHOT' in their url.

So you need to pass the bundle IDs or urls to the watch command, instead of *. Then Karaf will start watching this non "snapshot" bundles.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  yes!

The dev:* commands are really useful (dynamic-import is another good one).  If you see wiring errors when using dev:watch (i.e. starts referring to two versions of the same bundle, eg. bundle 37.0 and 37.1) then it's a good hint that packages from the original bundle are still being used - this indicates that references aren't being released properly.